# iPad displaying content larger then screen size/viewport

Tags: html, css, ipad, responsive-design

I have a website (http://ginkandgasoline.net). I have the viewport set to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

however the site is displaying larger then the screen size in portrait mode. The sub pages seem to be working fine its just the homepage. When I remove the viewport code the site fits the window but once the device is turned it keeps the current zoom and won't reset back to how it was set before rotated.

I have tried multiple options but don't really want to use media queries to resolve the issue. I have also tried solving the issue with as outlined by Jeremy Keith to no resolve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead...

```
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
```

I used something similar for a web app I was making and this fixed it.